# R programmable fixing of parameters in `optim`

Tags: r, optim

I am using `optim` to fit various probability distributions to two given tertiles `t1` and `t2`. The following function works, where `qfun` is the quantile function of the distribution and `par_start` gives the initial values of the parameters of the distribution:

```
tertile_fit <- function(t1, t2, qfun, par_start) {
  gapfn <- function(par, t1, t2, qfun) {
    a <- t1 - do.call(qfun, as.list(c(1/3, par)))
    b <- t2 - do.call(qfun, as.list(c(2/3, par)))
    a ^ 2 + b ^ 2
  }
  result <- optim(par = par_start, gapfn, t1 = t1, t2 = t2, qfun = qfun)
  if (result$convergence != 0) {
    stop("Optmisation failed")
  } else {  
    result$par %>% 
      as.list 
  }
}
```

The length of `par_start` determines how many of the distribution's parameters are  varied in the optimisation but very much restricts the choice: if `length(par_start) = 3` for example then the optimisation will be made over the first 3 parameters in `formals(qfun)`.

My problem is that for some distributions I want to be able to choose which parameters are to be fixed. I could solve that problem if I were writing specific code for each distribution by amending the `do.call` lines in `gapfn`, to include the names and values of the parameters I fix, for example:

```
do.call(qfun, as.list(c(1/3, mean = 0, par)))
```

with `par` now the parameters that are allowed to vary.

But what I want is a function that can take any probability distribution and fix named parameters. It might look something like this:

```
new_tertile_fit <- function(t1, t2, qfun, fixed_params, par_start)
```

where `fixed_params` is a data.frame(?) or a list(?) giving the names of the parameters and the values at which they are fixed.

What is giving me trouble is extracting that information from `fixed_params` so that the `do.call` lines can include the specific statements along the lines `par1 = 2` if `par1` is one of the parameters of the distribution being fitted.

Comment: Can you achieve what you want using `...`? (Check the help page `?dots`.) I don't really understand your question.

Comment: There are several alternatives to `optim` in the optimx package that support masks which are fixed parameters.

Comment: G. Grothendieck Many thanks for this suggestion but I am having trouble finding any examples in the `optimx` documentation. Can you point me to a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a parameter accepting a logical vector of length `length(par_start)` indicating if the corresponding parameter is supposed to be fixed:

```
tertile_fit <- function(t1, t2, qfun, par_start, fixed = logical(length(par_start))) {
  gapfn <- function(par, t1, t2, qfun) {
    par_start[!fixed] <- par
    a <- t1 - do.call(qfun, as.list(c(1/3, par_start)))
    b <- t2 - do.call(qfun, as.list(c(2/3, par_start)))
    a ^ 2 + b ^ 2
  }
  result <- optim(par = par_start[!fixed], gapfn, t1 = t1, t2 = t2, qfun = qfun)
  if (result$convergence != 0) {
    stop("Optmisation failed")
  } else {
    par_start[!fixed] <- result$par
  }
  par_start
}

# test with three-parameter beta (with non-centrality)
# don't fix any parameters
(par <- tertile_fit(0.5, 0.8, qbeta, c(1, 1, 1)))
#> [1] 1.0686711 0.8931586 1.0555377
qbeta((1:2)/3, par[1], par[2], par[3])
#> [1] 0.4999925 0.8000041

# fix the non-centrality parameter
(par <- tertile_fit(0.5, 0.8, qbeta, c(1, 1, 2), !2:0))
#> [1] 0.8132744 0.9571455 2.0000000
qbeta((1:2)/3, par[1], par[2], par[3])
#> [1] 0.4999997 0.7999982
```

However, if you try to fix one of two parameters, you'll get a warning (and you'll probably not fit your tertiles since you have one parameter and two constraints):

```
# test with gamma distribution, fixing the rate parameter
(par <- tertile_fit(0.5, 2, qgamma, c(1, 10), 0:1))
#> Warning in optim(par = par_start[!fixed], gapfn, t1 = t1, t2 = t2, qfun = qfun): one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
#> use "Brent" or optimize() directly
#> [1] 13.12813 10.00000
qgamma((1:2)/3, par[1], par[2])
#> [1] 1.131999 1.439610
```